# How to copy an object in the array to another array based on a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, arrayobject

I have an array

```
data = [
{code: 'A1', name: 'bag', qty: 3},
{code: 'A2', name: 'purse', qty: 2},
{code: 'A3', name: 'belt', qty: 1},
]
```

I want to omit `qty` & duplicate each item to another array based on each `qty` :

```
data = [
{code: 'A1', name: 'bag'},
{code: 'A1', name: 'bag'},
{code: 'A1', name: 'bag'},
{code: 'A2', name: 'purse'},
{code: 'A2', name: 'purse'},
{code: 'A3', name: 'belt'},
]
```

I've tried :

```
const [qtyList, setQtyList] = useState(
 new Array(renderData.length).fill(1)
);
const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState([])

const updatedQty = qtyList.map((q, index) => {
            if (index === k) return q = parseInt(val)
            else return q
        });
        setQtyList(updatedQty); //[3,2,1]

data.map((i, idx) => {
 let temp = []
 let existed = data.filter(x=>x.code==i.code).length
 for (let x=0; x<=qtyList[idx]; x++){
   temp.push(i)
 }
 setSelectedProduct((prev)=> [...prev, i])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code:

```js
var data = [
  { code: 'A1', name: 'bag', qty: 3 },
  { code: 'A2', name: 'purse', qty: 2 },
  { code: 'A3', name: 'belt', qty: 1 },
];

var newArray = data.map(x => {
  return Array(x.qty).fill({ code: x.code, name: x.name })
})

console.log([].concat.apply([], newArray))
```

Answer (score 2):

An example using `flatMap`

```js
const data = [
    { code: "A1", name: "bag", qty: 3 },
    { code: "A2", name: "purse", qty: 2 },
    { code: "A3", name: "belt", qty: 1 },
];

const o = data.flatMap(({ code, name, qty }) =>
    Array(qty).fill({ code, name })
);

console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
data.reduce((a,{qty, ...rest})=>a.concat(Array(qty).fill({...rest})),[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.map(item => Array(item.qty).fill({ code: item.code, name: item.name })).flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant solution to this problem, but this was my quick fix:

```
let data = [
{code: 'A1', name: 'bag', qty: 3},
{code: 'A2', name: 'purse', qty: 2},
{code: 'A3', name: 'belt', qty: 1},
]

let dupArr = []

data.map((i) =>{
   for(let j = 0;j<= i['qty']-1; j++){
       dupArr.push(i);
   }
});

dupArr.map((idx)=>{
    delete idx['qty'];
})

console.log(dupArr);
```